# What is wrong with "ethics was violating" in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

> He added: 'Dean and Jerome are Bad Attorneys they dont (sic) now (sic) what justice is and they dont (sic) now (sic) what is a (sic) investigation is because if they did they would have done it for a (sic) innocent man like me!!!
>
> *And I was on appeal and they were still talking about the case and that was there (sic) **ethics was (sic)** violating my appeal!!*

([Source: dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3711166/They-didn-t-job-Making-Murderer-jailed-subject-Steven-Avery-pens-letter-publicly-slamming-former-attorneys-missed-case.html))

This is a transcript from the handwritten letter where the grammatical mistakes are marked with "sic". I cannot find out what is wrong with "was" in the second sentence.

Comment: Which "was" do you refer? I think "ethics" is plural.

Comment: But what about the definition of Ethics in Wikipedia: Ethics or moral philosophy is the branch of philosophy that involves systematizing, defending, and recommending concepts of right and wrong conduct.

Comment: I see, but I think the context is not about that branch of science. is it?

Comment: "and that was there ethics" should be "and that was their ethics", although that still doesn't help the sentence much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject to some interpretation, but I think it should be:

> And I was on appeal and they were still talking about the case and that was **their** ethics <del>was</del> violating my appeal!!

There is one too many verbs.

Comment: @ColleenV I didn't check that far into the context (probably the quote needs to be expanded to get the proper context). I revised my answer so maybe it is now more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

**Ethics** is a plural noun and should take the plural form of the past tense of **to be**, which is **were**, not **was**.